# R clean way to plot densites from hdf5's

Tags: r, ggplot2

So I have an hdf5 file, it has 24 columns and many many rows.
Each row is a single observation.
Of the 24 columns 22 contain variables, 1 contains a target value that describes the 'truth value' of the observation and 1 contains a weight for that data point.

I would like to be able to plot the densities of each of the variables, to compare the distribution between truth values.

**Example**

Let us take this slightly simpler set-up for illustration;

```
example_data <- c(rnorm(20, 0, 0.5), rnorm(20, 1, 0.5), abs(rnorm(20, 0.5, 0.5)), sample(0:2, 20, replace=T))
data_mat <- matrix(example_data, nrow=20, ncol=4)
colnames(data_mat) <- c("cute.variable", "fuzzy.variable", "weight", "target")
```

Actually, I am getting my data from an hdf5 (with `h5read`) which yealds a matrix. I then read the column names in from another text file, as `h5read` seems to ignore that data.

Then, in order to plot the density function of each variable, split on target value, I do this;

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape)
# weigths
w_0_long = melt(data_mat[which(data_mat[,'target']==0), "weight"])
w_1_long = melt(data_mat[which(data_mat[,'target']==1), "weight"])
w_2_long = melt(data_mat[which(data_mat[,'target']==2), "weight"])

for(name in colnames(data_mat)){
  if(name == "target") next
  if(name == "weight") next
  # raw data
  var_0_long = melt(data_mat[which(data_mat[,'target']==0), name])
  var_1_long = melt(data_mat[which(data_mat[,'target']==1), name])
  var_2_long = melt(data_mat[which(data_mat[,'target']==2), name])

  raw_plot <- ggplot() + geom_density(aes(value), colour="red", data=var_0_long) + 
    geom_density(aes(value), colour="blue", data=var_1_long)+ 
    geom_density(aes(value), colour="green", data=var_2_long)
  print(raw_plot)

  readline(prompt="Press [enter] to continue")
  # weighted data
  weighted_plot <- ggplot() + geom_density(aes(value, weight=w_0_long), colour="red", data=var_0_long) + 
    geom_density(aes(value, weight=w_1_long), colour="blue", data=var_1_long)+ 
    geom_density(aes(value, weight=w_2_long), colour="green", data=var_2_long)
  print(weighted_plot)

  readline(prompt="Press [enter] to continue")
}
```

**question**

Surely there is a better way to plot the densities from the hdf5s?
Perhaps there is a way to convert the matrix to a data frame at the start, but I cannot seem to do it without manually adding all 22 variables, and I would rather not hard code that because it may well change. Besides, each target does not have the same number of variables, so there would still need to be a split by target at some point.

I do think I need it to be a `ggplot`, because that will calculate a weighted density plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can facet by `target` and fit them all on one plot:

```r
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(47)

# generate data
matrix(c(rnorm(20, 0, 0.5), 
         rnorm(20, 1, 0.5), 
         abs(rnorm(20, 0.5, 0.5)), 
         sample(0:2, 20, replace = TRUE)), 
       # dimensions
       nrow = 20, 
       ncol = 4, 
       # set column names
       dimnames = list(NULL, c("cute.variable", "fuzzy.variable", "weight", "target"))) %>% 
    # coerce to data frame
    as.data.frame() %>% 
    # reshape to long form
    gather(variable, value, contains('variable')) %>% 
    # plot, coercing `target` to factor so it's discrete
    ggplot(aes(value, weight = weight, color = factor(target), fill = factor(target))) + 
    geom_density(alpha = 0.3) + 
    # separate facets by `variable`
    facet_wrap(~variable)
#> Warning in density.default(x, weights = w, bw = bw, adjust = adjust, kernel
#> = kernel, : sum(weights) != 1 -- will not get true density
```

[image]

Note the warning, which may or may not be an issue.

Comment: Thanks, it's really useful to see more examples of ggplot, I'm getting to grips with it. So if you run the example you can see the plots I'm aiming for are not quite those. I need to compare the distribution of each variable between the targets. (e.g. does fuzzy have a sharper peak in target 1 or 2). So I am overlaying all the densities for one variable on each plot, as opposed to all the densities for one target on a plot. Also, I have 22 variables, so they do need to be on separate plots.

Comment: Ah, that's what I meant in my last note. Edited to switch the aesthetics, better?

Comment: @alistaire in the code, what is the meaning of NULL in list()?

Comment: `matrix` only has a `dimnames` parameter, so it needs a length-2 list for row and column names respectively. If one is `NULL`, it makes them up as usual.

Comment: Thank you, and apologies for the slow response. It's going to take me a little while to get to grips with what you have used, but it is working beautifully

Comment: I added some comments to help. Most of it is your code rearranged; the new parts are `gather` (instead of `melt`) and `facet_wrap`.

Comment: Ok, I get it now, thanks for the commenting too. Question; does using the `%>%` pipe, rather than assigning each variable and putting it in the arguments list, save ram or have another technical advantage?

Comment: Mostly it just makes the progression of the data through the code easier to see and keeps you from ending up with a lot of intermediary objects in your environment. Since you're not creating a binding to the intermediary objects, it does make it possible for `gc()` to clean them up quickly after the fact, so while you'll still need the same memory to run the code, it may help make the memory available to future code without explicit effort.